# Visual Studio Error undefined or null reference baseUri

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, office-js, office-addins

This is the error I get when I try to start the Office add-in in a browser:

[image]

What is this `baseUri`, where can I change it, and to which value would I change it?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but could you translate this into English? Normally I just allow Google or Bing to do this for me but being a png... :)

Comment: It says "The value may not be null. Parameter name: baseUri"

Comment: Can you add some details about the context? Are you getting this error when you press F5 in Visual Studio? An Office add-in won't run properly in a browser.